# Search for Property Types

Tags: xpath, aem, jcr

I have to convert property types from String to Long.

Now I want to search with XPath, QueryBuilder,... all properties "prop1" with type String to convert them into Long.

All queries I tried are giving only all nodes where "prop1" exists.

```
/jcr:root/content/dam/images//element(*,dam:Asset)[jcr:content/metadata/tiff:ImageLength]
```

Is there a possibility to do that? Because e.g. on http://docs.jboss.org/exojcr/1.12.13-GA/developer/en-US/html/ch-jcr-query-usecases.html I haven't found anything which helps me.

Greetings
Sören

Answer (score 2):

The only function related to property types offered by the JCR queries is the `CAST()`, but it doesn't allow you to filter the results. Therefore, you can't find nodes with given property type using XPath, SQL or SQL2. Filter the results manually, using JCR API and the [`Property#getType()`](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Property.html#getType()) method.